# Python - Pandas script too slow with Lambda

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

My code is working as i wish but is very slow when i run this line.

--- newdf['Login'] = newdf['Site'].apply(lambda x : "yes" if get(x).status_code == 200 else "no")  ---

After comment the code run fast.
How can i change this line to add a Yes or No to login column and keep fast?
And if i can improve all this i will be appreciative.
I hope I made understood myself.
Thank you!

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from requests import get
from requests.exceptions import HTTPError
lista = pd.read_csv('sites4.csv', sep=',')
df = pd.DataFrame(lista, columns=['Site', 'Login'])
newdf = df.assign(Site=df['Site'].map(str) + 'Login')

headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}

for i in newdf['Site']:
    try:
        result = get(i, headers=headers, timeout=5)
    except HTTPError as http_err:
        print(f'HTTP error occurred: {http_err}')
    except Exception as err:
        print(f'Other error occurred: {err}')
    else:
        if 'application/json' in result.headers.get('Content-Type') or result.status_code == 406 or result.status_code == 403:
            newdf['Login'] = newdf['Site'].apply(lambda x : "yes" if get(x).status_code == 200 else "no")
            print(i + ' é Login')
            print(result)
```

Comment: Do you realize that that line applies to every row in the dataframe?

Comment: yes, is exatcly what i want.   i want to check every row of my dataframe and see if return 200 or not and add a YES to my csv.

Comment: Now you are looping through the dataframe with the `for` loop, GET:ing each URL. For each URL that does not return an error,  but returns JSON, 403 or 406 you get *all*  URL:s — not just the one you just tested — again and update the entire dataframe. Is that really what you want?

Comment: ohhhh i see!! thank u!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### This Should Be a Much Faster Implementation of your Functions

```py
from typing import Optional, Coroutine, List
import aiohttp
from pandas import DataFrame
from pandas.errors import EmptyDataError
import pandas as pd
import asyncio


def create_df_form_file() -> Optional[DataFrame]:
    try:
        site_list = pd.read_csv('sites4.csv', sep=',')
        df = pd.DataFrame(site_list, columns=['Site', 'Login'])
        return df.assign(Site=df['Site'].map(str) + 'Login')
    except EmptyDataError as e:
        print(f'File Error: {e}')
    return None


new_df: Optional[DataFrame] = create_df_form_file()

if not isinstance(new_df, DataFrame):
    print("empty data goodbye")
    exit(1)


# NOTE: Async Get Request
async def get_request(x_url: str) -> bool:
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get(url=x_url) as result:
            return result.ok


# functions to test if site needs a login and if header contains json and to include Yes or No
def needs_login(result): return result.status == 406 or result.status == 403


def is_json(result): return result.headers.get('Content-Type') == 'application/json'


async def yes_no(x): return 'yes' if await get_request(x) else 'no'


async def _do_work(site_column, _headers: dict) -> Optional[DataFrame]:

    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get(site_column['Site'], headers=_headers) as result:
            if is_json(result) or needs_login(result):
                # Appending Yes No
                site_column['login'] = site_column['Site'].apply(yes_no)
                print(site_column['Site'] + ' é Login')
                print(result)
                return site_column
            return None


def get_results():
    global new_df
    headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    try:
        _coro: List[Coroutine] = [_do_work(site_column, _headers=headers) for site_column in new_df['Site']]
    except KeyError:
        print("please insure your input file is accurate")
        exit(1)

    try:
        event_loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    except RuntimeError:
        asyncio.set_event_loop(asyncio.new_event_loop())
        event_loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

    # noinspection PyUnboundLocalVariable
    results = event_loop.run_until_complete(*_coro)
    print(results)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    get_results()
```

[for more information on python programming please visit my tutorial site here](http://gcp-python-dev.site/)

Comment: Thank u so much!  Im studing the code:  for now im receiving this error 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\doug3\Projetos_PY\web_crawn\main.py", line 77, in <module>
    get_results()
  File "C:\Users\doug3\Projetos_PY\web_crawn\main.py", line 72, in get_results
    results = event_loop.run_until_complete(*_coro)
TypeError: run_until_complete() takes 2 positional arguments but 39 were given
sys:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine '_do_work' was never awaited

Comment: [_do_work(site_column=site_column, _headers=headers) ...


then     event_loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(*_coro))

Comment: sorry, i dont get it. :(

Comment: can u help me later? i really want run your code and study!

Answer (score 0):

because get is func in requests.

Since requests is not an asynchronous package, all codes are interrupted until the request is completed.

If you use asyncio and aiohttp, you can improve it.